# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError during String concatenation

Tags: java, out-of-memory, string-concatenation

I get java.lang.OutOfMemoryError during String concatenation. Can somebody help me get rid of this? Below is how my code looks. This whole if blokc is run under a loop and when it is processing string concatenation for "str", it throws OutofemoryError. Any help on this much appreciated.

```
for (long j = mincollectiontime; j <= maxcollectiontime; j = j
        + timeintreval) {
    query = "select count(*) table1";

    ResultSet result2 = VerticaDBHandler.executequery(con2, query);
    System.out.println("Query:- " + query);

    String str = "";
    if (result2.isBeforeFirst()) {
        if (mysqlconn == null) {
            mysqlconn = DatabaseHandler.openDB();
        }

        while (result2.next()) {
            int isgap = Integer.parseInt(result2.getString(1));
            if (isgap == 0) {
                Date startime = EpochTimeHandler.epochToTimeStamp(j);
                Date endtime = EpochTimeHandler.epochToTimeStamp(j
                        + timeintreval);
                str = "NO DATA BETWEEN " + startime + " --- " + endtime
                        + " forInstanceId: " + instanceid
                        + " --InstanceName: " + instanceName + " in "
                        + perfTables[i];
                DatabaseHandler.LoadDB_dataGaps(mysqlconn,
                        perfTables[i], instanceid, instanceName,
                        VirtType, BelongstoDataCenter,
                        startime.toString(), endtime.toString(), str);
                System.out.println(str);
                str = "";
            } else {
                System.out.println("No Gap Seen");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The exception.

```
Exception thrown:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap.newNode(LinkedHashMap.java:256)
    at java.util.HashMap.putVal(HashMap.java:630)
    at java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:611)
    at sun.util.resources.OpenListResourceBundle.loadLookup(OpenListResourceBundle.java:146)
    at sun.util.resources.OpenListResourceBundle.loadLookupTablesIfNecessary(OpenListResourceBundle.java:128)
    at sun.util.resources.OpenListResourceBundle.handleKeySet(OpenListResourceBundle.java:96)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.containsKey(ResourceBundle.java:1807)
    at sun.util.locale.provider.LocaleResources.getTimeZoneNames(LocaleResources.java:262)
    at sun.util.locale.provider.TimeZoneNameProviderImpl.getDisplayNameArray(TimeZoneNameProviderImpl.java:122)
    at sun.util.locale.provider.TimeZoneNameProviderImpl.getDisplayName(TimeZoneNameProviderImpl.java:98)
    at sun.util.locale.provider.TimeZoneNameUtility$TimeZoneNameGetter.getName(TimeZoneNameUtility.java:325)
    at sun.util.locale.provider.TimeZoneNameUtility$TimeZoneNameGetter.getObject(TimeZoneNameUtility.java:281)
    at sun.util.locale.provider.TimeZoneNameUtility$TimeZoneNameGetter.getObject(TimeZoneNameUtility.java:267)
    at sun.util.locale.provider.LocaleServiceProviderPool.getLocalizedObjectImpl(LocaleServiceProviderPool.java:281)
    at sun.util.locale.provider.LocaleServiceProviderPool.getLocalizedObject(LocaleServiceProviderPool.java:265)
    at sun.util.locale.provider.TimeZoneNameUtility.retrieveDisplayName(TimeZoneNameUtility.java:135)
    at java.util.TimeZone.getDisplayName(TimeZone.java:400)
    at java.util.Date.toString(Date.java:1045)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2982)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at com.test.perf.testpgm.main(testpgm.java:112)
```

Comment: Need to see more code. Post the for loop? Also, what have you already tried? Have you tried a debugger?

Comment: could you paste the entire class

Comment: Complete code is edited inline above

Comment: I don't think your issue is related to string concatenation, I think you're just loading more data than fits into your memory. Look at the stack trace...

Comment: Can you highlight the line of code `testpgm.java:112` where the error originates

Comment: str = "NO DATA BETWEEN " +startime+ " --- " +endtime+ " for InstanceId: " + instanceid  + " --InstanceName: " +instanceName+ " in " +perfTables[i];

is the line of code where the error occurs

Comment: @VikramJere Sorry if its stupid, but what does EpochTimeHandler.epochToTimeStamp(j) supposed to return?

Comment: what does perfTables[i]; returns ???

Comment: There me some other problem, as your code in first look, works fine. But no idea about other class methods called from the function. Please check whether the other method working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like here is the Problem.

```
for (long j = mincollectiontime; j <= maxcollectiontime; j = j + timeintreval)
```

You are definitely ruling out the maximum lengh and giving a call in the function. Please post more code so that, specific problem can be noticed.

Answer (score 0):

May be this issue is not related to string concationation, I think this issue with Heap size. Once increase the heap size of your IDE and run the program.